# does my function need synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I will have multi-thread using one static variable. This variable will be updated when thread is running. Update process will be done by `updateModel` function. Here is the snippet of my code

```
public static int total = 0;
...
run(){
   // there will be calculation before update value ex: int ext = this.total/10
   updateModel();
}

synchronized void updatedModel(){
   this.total += 1;
}
```

Does updateModel need synchronized?

Comment: Do you really have to update total in a thread?

Comment: I'd recommend you to use AtomicInteger instead. That way doesn't need synchronization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing wrong here, you are using `this` reference to synchronize the static variable, since the method `updatedModel()` is instance. `It's not thread safe anyway!`

Use a static reference to synchronize a static content or make that method `updatedModel()` static

Comment: @IniKoqApah : Yes, that's one possible solution.

Comment: thank you, I just read some tutorial, this is the biggest mistake of java programmer, forget to use static for static variable that need to be synchronized

Answer (score 3):

> I will have multi-thread using one static variable.

Yes , that variable needs to be synchronized and good sign to use  [`AtomicInteger.`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Keep that method as it is. make variable thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

When I remember right, `+=` isn't an atomic operation, so it can occur that one thread enters `updateModel` and reads value `42`, then context switch and another thread enters `updateModel`, reads value `42`, increments it to `43`, then context switch and a third thread enters `updateModel`, reads value `43`, increments it to `44`, then context switch and the first thread sets the value to `43` again. So, if you want to guarantee that every thread increments the value by 1, you should synchronize it.